# How to performing Quality Control in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssis

I am very new to SQL Server.  I am trying to determine the best way to conduct quality control of data stored within a SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition database.

The types of QC tests to be conducted include data integrity, referential integrity, and business logic checks.  The output needs to be a table where each record represents a dataset tested and each column represents a test conducted.  Depending on the test, values for each column should either be a number representing how many records in the dataset failed, or a list of ID's representing records that failed.

I'm not sure where to begin...  Can this be done using simple SQL queries or should this be done using Reporting Services or some other tool provided with SQL Server?

Comment: Are these tests going to eventually sit on a production environment or are you hoping to set this up just for test purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by building your queries in SSMS.

Once you get to stable queries, then you could go to SSRS if you want to enhance the presentation and delivery of the data, or to SSIS if you want to automate and flexibility to output to many different systems, or look at a simple SQL Agent job if you just want to copy data to a different table.

SSRS is aimed at read-only access with nice graphical presentation and delivery formats.
SSIS is aimed at flexible data integration tasks, but not much UI.

SSMS is the general purpose SQL server authoring tool. Both SSRS and SSIS can use the SQL you write in SSMS.

(I think this answers your question; Is this what you were looking for?)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am going to start looking into SSRS and SSIS more.  I have used SSIS briefly for importing/exporting data to Excel, but don't know much more than that.  I have never used SSRS.  I just rewrote the question to try and simplify what I am asking, but I think your answer is a step in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you want to stick with simple SQL queries for your development. Then, if those queries are fairly well self contained, schedule them with a SQL Agent job. If they interact with other data sources/destinations, use an SSIS package and schedule that. Once you are there, then look at SSRS to email a good looking chart with the results.